# Unable to find the internal logging class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging$class

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, gwas, hail

I am trying to build spark cluster on [DNAnexus platform](https://www.dnanexus.com/).

I tried creating spark context from jupyterlab notebook.

```py
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession(sc)
```

I get the following error stack trace.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging$class
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.<init>(DAGScheduler.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.<init>(DAGScheduler.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.<init>(DAGScheduler.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:536)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

I checked the jar files and I could not find which jar file is required for internal logging class.
Can someone point out whether my spark installation is faulty or which jar file is required for missing class?

Comment: Does this https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#tab_python_0 answer your query?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have already gone through it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason, why do you wanna create a `SparkSession` that way?

Comment: No specific reason - I have my config already defined in environment variables while creating spark cluster. Is there any benefit in defining the other way?

Comment: How did you get it up and running?

Comment: I found it later on to be bad installation. So, I reinstalled spark and I got it to work.